# Randbetween 1 and 4, excluding the value to the left, and maintaining the count for each number

Tags: excel, random, combinatorics, countif

I have the following array in excel. In the second column are numbers I have chosen between 1 and 4 so that the count of each value is either 3 or 4. I.e., four 1's, three 2's, four 3's, and three 4's. I chose these values arbitrarily.

[image: Array]

This is meant to be a way to make sure members in the set do not have the same number (1-4) more than once.

The value in column C (Lab 3-4) should follow these criteria

- Random integer between 1 and 4 that is not equal to the value in column B (Lab 1-2). `CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),IF([@[Lab 1-2]]=1,2,RANDBETWEEN(1,[@[Lab 1-2]]-1)),IF([@[Lab 1-2]]=4,3,RANDBETWEEN([@[Lab 1-2]]+1,4)))`
- The number of 1's equals 4, the number of 2's equals 3, the number of 3's equals 4, and the number of 4's equals 3. **This criteria can be relaxed so that 2 numbers only repeat 3 times and the remaining repeat 4 times.**
- The value in column D cannot be the same as the value in B.

The array below shows the result of applying the first condition. I successfully generated the random number, but I have no way of controlling the number of times each integer is repeated. I would have to apply a similar process for column D (Lab 5-6) but it would need to include columns B and C.

The if statements also include a 2 or 3 arbitrarily to make the script work and I guess this is where the code should be updated.

**Is there a way to generate random integers like this while making sure the number of repetitions follows the criteria in my second bullet?**
As I mentioned above, I can relax the second condition but I'm not sure if that makes it easier or harder to implement.

[image: Array2]

Comment: It looks like an integer optimization problem, have you try to use [Solver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040)? On the other hand what is the general rule for the second bullet? you mentioned it can be relaxed, so what is the constraint for the general case?

Comment: This is the first time I'm hearing about the Solver capability in excel. Two numbers out of the four must be repeated four times, the other two can be repeated three times. It does not have to be strictly 1->4, 2->3, 3->4, and 4->3.